# EmguCv webcam capture conflicts with Windows Media Player

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv, emgucv, windows-media-player

For an educational game i am developing, i need to capture webcam video, do real time face tracking, do marker detection, display augmentations and play sound. As this is a rebuild of an existing Silverlight game i decided to build it in WPF, so i could reuse the XAML.

All graphics related requirements (capture, detection, tracking, etc) have been successfully implemented using functions from the EmguCv library.

As far as i know, in order to play audio (mp3 files) from within a WPF app, i have a few options:

1. Use the MediaElement (requires Windows Media Player)
2. Use the MediaPlayer class (requires Windows Media Player) <== Preferred
3. Use a (the only?) 3rd party library like NAudio

Now, all seems well. I can play mp3 files using any of the above method.

The problem is that playing the mp3 files, while capturing webcam frames causes the `Emgu.CV.Capture` to somehow always return the same frame. If i ask the Capture object to flip the frame horizontally by default (more natural) i keep getting the same frame flipped on every request (so ltr-rtl-ltr-rtl-ect.). Even after completing playback of the mp3 file, the Capture object is stuck in this apparent infinite loop.

It seems to me that the Capture is actually not capturing anything anymore, but just returns the last grabbed frame over and over again.

No exceptions are thrown but CPU spikes. The profiler (Jetbrains) tells me that the `Capture.QueryFrame` method uses most CPU cycles.

Below a small demo program to reproduce the issue:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using Emgu.CV;

namespace DI.Sandbox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly Capture _capture;
        private readonly MediaPlayer _player;
        private readonly DispatcherTimer _timer;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _capture = new Capture { FlipHorizontal = true };
            _player = new MediaPlayer { Volume = 1 };
            _timer = new DispatcherTimer {Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000/24)};
            _timer.Tick += GameLoop;
        }

        private void GameLoop(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var grab = _capture.QueryFrame())
            {
                Capture.Source = BitmapSourceConvert.ToBitmapSource(grab);
            }
        }

        private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private void Play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _player.Open(new Uri("assets\\test.mp3", UriKind.Relative));
            _player.Play();
        }

        private void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _player.Stop();
            _timer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

... and ...

```
<Window x:Class="DI.Sandbox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="OpenCV Face Tracking Experiment" Width="800" Height="600" ResizeMode="NoResize">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Name="Start" Width="100" Height="25" Click="Start_Click" Grid.Column="0">Start</Button>
            <Button Name="Play" Width="100" Height="25" Click="Play_Click" Grid.Column="1">Play</Button>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBlock Name="Answer" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Name="Elapsed" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button Name="Stop" Width="100" Height="25" Click="Stop_Click" Grid.Column="2">Stop</Button>
        </Grid>

        <Image Name="Capture" Grid.Row="1" Width="640" Height="480" Margin="5"></Image>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Weirdest thing is that i can replicate the same problem by, running my app without playing audio, and then playing any mp3 file in the Windows Media Player!

Questions:

1. Has anyone else experienced this issue? (i googled but found no similar reports)
2. Does anyone know a workaround?
3. What other alternatives do i have to play audio from within my WPF app?

**Update:I have tested this on Windows 8 only**